# SQL Server - Need to backfill a column in a table with a billion records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I need to back fill a datetime column into in an existing sql server table (A) with a billion records.
Im inner joining the target table (A) with the parent table (B) on primary key (ID) and then retriving the dates.
Unforunately, i dont have an index on the date column which is causing the update to be very slow.
I m not able to create an index on Date column (ID as include) since the online index creation is eating up the whole tlog (150gb max) and offine index build is out of scope.

```
UPDATE  A
    SET A.DATE = ZZ.DATE
FROM    A
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT TOP 100000 A.ID,
                           B.DATE
         FROM   A WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN
                B WITH (NOLOCK)
                -- parent table
                ON A.ID = B.ID
         WHERE  A.DATE IS NULL) AS ZZ
        ON ZZ.ID = A.ID;
```

Any expert suggetions to perform the backfill in faster or efficent way .

Thanks

Comment: If you are in a situation where you *physically cannot do* bulk data changes you are facing a lot of risk. What if someone accidentally drops an index? You *cannot* get it back then...

Comment: Any reason why you are accessing table A twice? Seems like a needless perf hit.

Comment: Im inserting in 100K or sometimes 1mil loops to avoid locks/performance issues, cant join directly with the parent table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE  A
    SET A.DATE = ZZ.DATE
FROM    A
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT  A.ID, B.DATE
         FROM   A WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN
                B WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON A.ID = B.ID

         WHERE  A.DATE IS NULL AND A.ID BETWEEN @a and @a + 100000
) AS ZZ
ON ( ZZ.ID = A.ID )
SET @X = @X + 100000
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case for chunked updates. Incidentally a very exhaustive post has been written on this topic recently (http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes). It deals with log management issues.

Basically, you should split the updates that you do into batches that are as large as possible while not causing too much log usage. You can either split on A (update ranges of A.ID) or split on b (pull the data from B according some data range that is indexed on B (for example the clustered index or any other index).

You select a range of rows using `WHERE ID BETWEEN @a AND @b`. If `ID` is indexed you avoid a table scan and can do incremental data pulls.

Comment: You can write your loop generically and pass in the number of records to update at a time, the log backup location and add a check to see if an external process wants to terminate the loop gracefully. Example: `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.RecordControls WHERE ProcedureName = N'up_UpdateProductDates' AND [State] = 'INTENT_STOP') BEGIN BREAK; END`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code, it removed one-time inner join, and commit per batch. Remove one-time hash join probably will not help you a lot, but maybe worth a try.

And another thing is, you mention you can't do online index creation, can you do an online index update/re-build, you can add you date column to your cluster index on ID, include your [date] in you cluster index. Since in my query, the where clause has the ID as condition, as well as [date], so, if you can add [date] to your ID index, it will help performance a lot, it will have no table scan, only cluster index seek.

```
DECLARE @ID BIGINT
SELECT @ID = MIN(ID) FROM A
WHILE @ID < IDENT_CURRENT('DBO.A')
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
        UPDATE A
        SET A.DATE = B.DATE
        FROM A
        INNER JOIN B (nolock)
        ON A.ID = B.ID
        WHERE A.ID BETWEEN @ID AND @ID + 100000
        AND A.DATE IS NULL
    COMMIT TRAN
    SET @ID = @ID + 100000
END
```

Comment: Thanks Ljh, but i cant use this query since it would do a direct update on the production system (isolation mode : Read committed), this would cause locking since both the tables are highly updated by app layer. Thats the reason im using an extra inner join and selecting the rows with a nolock so that atleast the row lookups (in my query) will not cause any locks

Comment: Update the code a little bit, add (nolock) to table B. Regarding to table A, no matter you use which kind query to update table A, the rows or page, or key range, depends on how much you really update, they will be put an update lock, that's why I add commit tran each, after each batch completed, lock will be released. Certainly during update lock period, you app layer can not update same rows or same range, but query will be ok, since share lock is compatible with update lock. If you say your query has no lock or less lock, I don't think that is right. I could be wrong...

Comment: Thanks ljh and usr .. you guys set me in the right direction, below is my updated query. This query is doing  2 million updates a minute where as my original query was doing like 15 mil a day

Comment: Awesome!!When come to your question, you know the best.